# As someone who knows next to nothing about law

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, broad-questions

What types of questions do you wish people would ask about law? 
What areas of the legal system should the public be more educated about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time we (the community) are still developing precedents for questions that are on-topic for the site.

Conjuring questions is a bit hard, and to be honest, I would probably just ask them if I had them.

I'm studying law because I think people, in general, should be more knowledgeable about the law, since it impinges on most people for most of their lives, if not all people for all of their lives.